# Call multiple stored procedures with from one stored procedure with multiple transactions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure called `run_proc` which calls three other stored procedures where the result of one stored procedure execute another stored procedure as a parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_proc() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ DECLARE
    _store RECORD;
    _date RECORD; BEGIN
    CALL sp1();
    FOR _store IN SELECT * FROM temp_stores
    LOOP
        CALL sp2(_store.store_id);
        -- Check if temp_year_month has any data
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_year_month) THEN
            FOR _date IN SELECT * FROM temp_year_month
            LOOP
                CALL sp3(_store.store_id, _date.year_month);
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
        -- Drop dates table after use
        DROP TABLE temp_year_month;
    END LOOP;
    -- Don't forget to drop the tenants table when done
    DROP TABLE temp_stores; END; $$
```

The above procedure works as expected, however in temp_stores contains around 1000 records, the above stored procedure executes and commits the result all at once into DB (sp3 contains some inserts/update statements), how can I make each `_store` value from `temp_stores` commits individually into DB, as PostgreSQL directly won't support autonomous transactions, is there a way to deal with it?

Comment: have you read the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html

Answer (score -1):

```
CREAR O REEMPLAZAR FUNCIÓN run_proc() RETORNA VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    _store RECORD;
    _fecha RECORD;
BEGIN
    
    FOR _store IN SELECT * FROM temp_stores LOOP
        
        CALL sp2(_store.store_id);

       
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_year_month) THEN
            
            FOR _date IN SELECT * FROM temp_year_month LOOP
                
                CALL sp3(_store.store_id, _date.year_month);
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
        DROP TABLE temp_year_month;
    END LOOP;

    DROP TABLE temp_stores;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

With this PL/pgSQL function, each _store value of temp_stores will be individually committed to the database due to the use of the FOR control structure... LOOP and the grouping of SP calls within a BEGIN and END block. Each iteration will behave as an individual transaction in the context of the PL/pgSQL function, allowing you to run SPs and commit changes to the database independently for each value in _store.

Comment: You need an explicit commit to finish a transaction and start a new one, as the docs you linked to show.